# CircleAvatar radius also zooms?

Tags: flutter

I have the following code

```
 Container(
   height: 90,
   width: 375,
   child: ListTile(
     leading: friendRequest.photoUrl == null
       ? null
       : CircleAvatar(
           backgroundImage: CachedNetworkImageProvider(friendRequest.photoUrl),
           radius: 40,
         ),
```

Which renders as expected

[image]

I want the avatar bigger, so set radius to a higher value, which makes the image bigger, but also zooms in so I now see less. Below is set to radius:40

[image]

Is there something else I need to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possibly this??

```
leading: FittedBox(
  fit: BoxFit.cover,
  child: CircleAvatar(
    backgroundImage: CachedNetworkImageProvider(//your image),
    radius: 40,
  ),
),
```

Comment: Worked great! Thanks! The other weird thing I'm seeing is I can't make the radius larger than 30. I'm not getting errors, it's just that values larger than 30 all render the same (which is the size I'm showing in my second screenshot). Any thoughts? It happens with and without your FittedBox fix

Comment: Well `ListTile()`  is somewhat of a basic built-in widget that can only be a certain height. That's why increasing the radius won't do anything since there is a max height for the ListTile.